# Doing a if else on the select tag options in pure Js?

Tags: javascript

I recently asked how I can do this is pure jQuery in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601435/keyboard-keys-and-arrows-dont-work-with-this-script-correctly/) but my client needs this to be done in a pure JS structure not jQuery based don't ask me why that's what he want's so how can I do a if else on the select tag options

values so for example if I use the keyboard or the mouse to change the values in the select tag options I expect a if else to be performed on the targeted select tag option or options here is my code which I need it to work properly with the keyboard as well.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.querySelector('#numbers').addEventListener('click',numbersResponse);

function numbersResponse(){
 var numberX= document.querySelector('#numbers').value;
  
  if(numberX == 'one'){
    document.querySelector('#numbersMessage').innerHTML= 'You selected: ' + numberX;
  }
  
  else if(numberX == 'two'){
    document.querySelector('#numbersMessage').innerHTML= 'You selected: ' + numberX;
  }
  
  else if(numberX == 'three'){
    document.querySelector('#numbersMessage').innerHTML= 'You selected: ' + numberX;
  }
  
}
  
});
```

```html
<select id='numbers'>
<option value='one'>1</option>
<option value='two'>2</option>
<option value='three'>3</option>
</select>

<p id='numbersMessage'></p>
```

Comment: That is pure JS, already. Use a `change` Event, instead of a `click` Event on `<select>`s, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a `change` listener instead of a `click` listener, and the listener will trigger whenever the `option` changes, even if not clicked on. Also, when setting text, assign to `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` - it's safer.

```js
const numbers = document.querySelector('#numbers');
numbers.addEventListener('change', numbersResponse);
function numbersResponse() {
  const numberX = numbers.value;
  const numbersMessage = document.querySelector('#numbersMessage')
  if (numberX == 'one') numbersMessage.textContent = 'You selected: ' + numberX;
  else if (numberX == 'two') numbersMessage.textContent = 'You selected: ' + numberX;
  else if (numberX == 'three') numbersMessage.textContent = 'You selected: ' + numberX;
}
```

```html
<select id='numbers'>
  <option value='one'>1</option>
  <option value='two'>2</option>
  <option value='three'>3</option>
</select>

<p id='numbersMessage'></p>
```

Comment: Lol I feel so dumb It's kind of like the jQuery version were they just added a change keyword I did not know JavaScript had something like that as well like the jQuery example thank you very much CertainPerformance My client will be happier now thanks to you :)!

Comment: I will grant you the best answer in a few mins ok stackoverflow said it is to soon to grant the best answer right now I have to wait a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change click event to change event to make work the listener properly and also as I can see we are printing the same response, so we can avoid if/else condition and print selected option directly.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.querySelector('#numbers').addEventListener('change',numbersResponse);

function numbersResponse(){
 var numberX= document.querySelector('#numbers').value;
 document.querySelector('#numbersMessage').innerHTML= 'You selected: ' + numberX;
  
}
  
});
```

```html
<select id='numbers'>
<option value='one'>1</option>
<option value='two'>2</option>
<option value='three'>3</option>
</select>

<p id='numbersMessage'></p>
```

Alternatively you can use Switch condition, it helps in better performance as well.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.querySelector('#numbers').addEventListener('change', numbersResponse);

  function numbersResponse() {
    var numberX = document.querySelector('#numbers').value;
    var print = '';
    switch (numberX) {
      case 'one':
        print = 'one';
        break;
      case 'two':
        print = 'two';
        break;
      case 'three':
        print = 'three';
        break;
    }
    document.querySelector('#numbersMessage').innerText= 'You selected: ' + print;

  }

});
```

```html
<select id='numbers'>
  <option value='one'>1</option>
  <option value='two'>2</option>
  <option value='three'>3</option>
</select>

<p id='numbersMessage'></p>
```